# Why do these NSNotifications repeat?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotifications

i am doing a in app purchase section which has a notification setting which pass the notification from observer class to main class. I have this code

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                // Item is still in the process of being purchased

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                // Item was successfully purchased!

                // --- UNLOCK FEATURE OR DOWNLOAD CONTENT HERE ---
                // The purchased item ID is accessible via 
                // transaction.payment.productIdentifier


                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_DataComplete object:nil] ;
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_DataCompletehindi object:nil];
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_DataCompletetamil object:nil];
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_DataCompletetelugu object:nil];
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_DataCompletekannada object:nil];
                // After customer has successfully received purchased content,
                // remove the finished transaction from the payment queue.
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];


            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                // Verified that user has already paid for this item.
                // Ideal for restoring item across all devices of this customer.

                // --- UNLOCK FEATURE OR DOWNLOAD CONTENT HERE ---
                // The purchased item ID is accessible via 
                // transaction.payment.productIdentifier

                // After customer has restored purchased content on this device,
                // remove the finished transaction from the payment queue.
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                // Purchase was either cancelled by user or an error occurred.
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_Datacomplteing object:nil];
                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
}
                // Finished transactions should be removed from the payment queue.
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I pass this notification to my main class, but I am getting repeated notifications.  The notification repeats every time and I didn't get the correct notification from observer class corresponding to the name of the notification. How do I solve this.

EDIT:
I have five alertviews like this:

```
if
{
}
elseif
{
}
else if
{
}
else if(alertView == kannadaPurchasedAlert)
{
    if (buttonIndex==0)
    {                        
        NSString *connectionstring =  [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

        if ([connectionstring length]==0) {
            proAlertView *alert = [[proAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"you are not connected to the internet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0] withStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:0.0 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
   }
   else
   { 
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinBegininapp) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        // Replace "Your IAP Product ID" with your actual In-App Purchase Product ID.
        SKPayment *paymentRequest = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier: @"com.touch.MyApp.MyApp.Kannada"]; 

        // Assign an Observer class to the SKPaymentTransactionObserver,
        // so that it can monitor the transaction status.
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:inappObserver];

        // Request a purchase of the selected item.
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:paymentRequest];
        // Register observer for when download of data is complete
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(downloadDataCompletekannada:) name:NOTIF_DataCompletekannada object:nil]; 
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(downloadDataCompleting:) name:NOTIF_Datacomplteing object:nil]; 
        amtk = 0.0;                         
   } 
}
```

then in .h file
I put

```
extern NSString * const NOTIF_DataComplete;
extern NSString * const NOTIF_Datacomplteing;
extern NSString * const NOTIF_FIRSTLAUNCH;
extern NSString * const NOTIF_DataCompletehindi;
extern NSString * const NOTIF_DataCompletetamil;
extern NSString * const NOTIF_DataCompletetelugu;
extern NSString * const NOTIF_DataCompletekannada;
```

Comment: Can you post the part of your main class where you addObserver for those notifications?

Comment: @danh yeaa sure,thanks for the reply.i have 5 langugepack of book to download with  diffrent product ID of inapp.so i have 5 buttons also,each button corresponds the each language pack,so i pass the notification accroding to the name.please see my edit.

Comment: @danh one more thing,evry thing works perfect if i tap the button with first notification and then second,for example ,i tap ther button with this NOTIF_DataComplete,then NOTIF_DataCompletehindi then,then ,i follw the order i get the correct response.if i tap the notification including NOTIF_DataCompletekannada this for the first time i will get the NOTIF_DataComplete this notification

Comment: Do you only subscribe to only two of the five? If any of those addObserver calls use the same selector as the any other, you will see that selector invoked once for each name.

Answer (score 0):

Where are your `NOTIF_DataCompleteXXX` declared ? If you don't assign them any string, they are all the same "empty-named" notification, and each one triggers all observers.

Comment: haii i put this before implemention file of main class like this...NSString * const NOTIF_DataComplete = @"DataComplete";
NSString * const NOTIF_Datacomplteing = @"DataCompleting";
NSString * const NOTIF_DataCompletehindi = @"DataCompletehindi";
NSString * const NOTIF_DataCompletetamil = @"DataCompletetamil";
NSString * const NOTIF_DataCompletetelugu = @"DataCompletetelugu";
NSString * const NOTIF_DataCompletekannada = @"DataCompletekannada";

Answer (score 0):

THe problem probably lay where you addObservers.  Those are cumulative, meaning each time you call it a new callback is registered with the notification center. If you call it a single time in a method, make sure that method is only called once. For example, the viewDidAppear: method may get called multiple times in the lifecycle of a view controller.  It's best to setup observers in viewDidLoad and to release them in your dealloc method.